# How to include OAuth headers into async fetch request?

Tags: java, google-app-engine, asynchronous, oauth, google-apps-script

I would like to use asynchronous requests in my google engine application to trigger google app script (which is deployed as web app) :

```
URLFetchService fetcher = URLFetchServiceFactory.getURLFetchService();
Future future = fetcher.fetchAsync(req);
HTTPResponse response = (HTTPResponse) future.get();
```

but fetchAsync method accepts only urls or **com.google.appengine.api.urlfetch.HTTPRequest**
which does not offer much more options : https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/java/javadoc/com/google/appengine/api/urlfetch/HTTPRequest

I do not see way how to add OAuth security headers into asynchrounous fetch service. We build authorized requests by using standart HttpRequest method.

Sample HttpRequest with included OAuth :

```
 HttpRequest contactrequest = rf.buildGetRequest(shortenEndpoint);
    GoogleHeaders headers = new GoogleHeaders();
    headers.setContentType("application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
    headers.setAuthorization("OAuth " + creds.getAccessToken());
    contactrequest.setHeaders(headers);
    contactrequest.getHeaders().set("GData-Version", "3.0");
```

Is there a way how to send async OAuth authorized requests ?

Comment: I am a bit unclear - are you trying to call the App Engine service from Apps Script or the other way around? If its from Apps Script -> App Engine, there is no such thing as Async Request - everything is synchronous there.

Comment: Google Engine -> Googe app script, that`s why you see only Java code here, not javascript. Generally speaking : i need to invoke url with OAuth headers included asynchronously from Google App Engine.

Comment: Ok, and to confirm this works correctly with simple HTTP requests or CURL with oAuth headers to the App Script service? I am not certain that Apps Script services can accept in oAuth tokens from other services but I haven't tried it either.

Answer (score 0):

Answer : OAuth headers cannot be specified in fetchAsync service. Alternative is use queque tasks.

Now new question come up : how to pass 'user context' when you invoking google app script programatically : [Invoking Google App script programatically and user identity?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13752159/invoking-google-app-script-programatically-and-user-identity) ?