# Invoking Google App script programatically and user identity?

Tags: java, cookies, oauth, google-apps-script

Google app script can be deployed as web app and triggered when you access given url.

When you trigger google app script programatically (e.g. from google engine application) how you can specify 'user context' ? Any special headers parameters ?

From browser it works  seamlessly : you are logged in your google account and when you visit google app script on your app domain it`s triggered and executed in your 'user context'. How doest that works ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Currently, you can't do this. Sorry!

Comment: As user is logged in my google app engine application will create sneaky iframe which sends request from the browser. Not nice but it will work.